# web page scrolls to top when pointer passes over a submit button - but not always

Tags: html, css, forms

I have a page on our members' web site (restricted access) that has, low down on the page, a couple of buttons to navigate elsewhere. For the vast majority of people these work perfectly but a few people have reported that with Windows 7 (64 bit) and Internet Explorer 11 when trying to click the buttons the page scrolls straight to the top! Other combinations of OS and browser seem not to give this behaviour and when I used this combination I had no problems. (Makes fault finding difficult!) I've searched the internet (Google and MSN)  but not found anything relevant.

I'd be very grateful for any ideas on where I should look to find a solution.

The page is written using PHP but no other scripting; the style sheet addresses neither forms nor buttons. The code for one of the buttons follows, the other is essentially identical except it directs to a different page.

```
       <form id="form1" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"  action="http://www.hmrs.org.uk/stewards/stewardslistM.php" target="public">
    <input type="hidden" id="member" name="member" value="<?php echo $HMRSno ; ?>">
    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="List of Stewards">
    &nbsp;and on to the Stewards&apos;s own pages.
   </form>
```

Comment: Does the URL change? Do the user(s) have any plug-ins added? I'd try running this on a machine experience the issue if possible. This also doesn't seem relevant to the PHP thread because PHP wouldn't cause this issue.

Comment: No to your questions. Regret I  don't have access to the machines showing the problems. I couldn't think how the issue could be related to PHP (or HTML or CSS) either.   Thanks for the suggestions.